# Manually compute the regression coefficients of a multiple regression model with numerical and categorical variables

Tags: r, regression, least-squares, regression-coefficients

I am going to explain my question using a reproducibile toy example. I would like to regress a numerical variable using a multiple regression model with either numerical and categorical variables. I would like to do that without using the functions provided by R, but I am worried that I am not coding the categorical variables properly. These are the toy data:

```
  mydata <- read.csv("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")

  mydata$admit <- factor(mydata$admit)
  mydata$gre <- scale(mydata$gre)
  mydata$gpa <- scale(mydata$gpa)
  mydata$rank <- factor(mydata$rank)

  head(mydata)

          admit        gre        gpa rank
        1     0 -1.7980110  0.5783479    3
        2     1  0.6258844  0.7360075    3
        3     1  1.8378321  1.6031352    1
        4     1  0.4527490 -0.5252692    4
        5     0 -0.5860633 -1.2084607    4
        6     1  1.4915613 -1.0245245    2

  model <- lm(gpa ~. , data=mydata)
  #linear multiple regression
  summary(model)
```

This is the result using the lm function:

```
  Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
  (Intercept) -0.04585    0.12924  -0.355   0.7230    
  admit1       0.24980    0.10273   2.432   0.0155 *  
  gre          0.36816    0.04672   7.879 3.24e-14 ***
  rank2       -0.14424    0.13993  -1.031   0.3033    
  rank3        0.14189    0.14723   0.964   0.3358    
  rank4       -0.13094    0.16620  -0.788   0.4313
```

Manually, I am coding the model matrix X in this way:

```
  mydata$rank2 <- sapply(mydata$rank, function (x){ if(x==2) return(1) else return(0)})
  mydata$rank3 <- sapply(mydata$rank, function (x){ if(x==3) return(1) else return(0)})
  mydata$rank4 <- sapply(mydata$rank, function (x){ if(x==4) return(1) else return(0)})

  X <- data.matrix(mydata[,-c(3,4)])
  Y <- data.matrix(mydata[,3])
  X[,1] <- X[,1] - 1
```

So I am creating for each level a binary variable and I am not considering the first level as I saw in the literature. This is the final matrix

```
  head(X)
       admit        gre rank2 rank3 rank4
  [1,]     0 -1.7980110     0     1     0
  [2,]     1  0.6258844     0     1     0
  [3,]     1  1.8378321     0     0     0
  [4,]     1  0.4527490     0     0     1
  [5,]     0 -0.5860633     0     0     1
  [6,]     1  1.4915613     1     0     0
```

but when I compute the regression coefficients in this way:

```
  Xbeta <- solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% t(X) %*% Y
```

I am obtaining different values compared with the ones obtained with lm.
In particular, these are:

```
               [,1]
  admit  0.23456544
  gre    0.36804870
  rank2 -0.18463006
  rank3  0.09954882
  rank4 -0.17408055
```

What I am doing wrong, please? I would like also to compute the residuals, the sd of the coefficients and the t-statistic, but again I am not obtaining the same results of the lm function for them, and I believe it is due to the fact that I am coding in a wrong way the categorical variables.

Comment: Think about a model with just one categorical predictor to start with. Why, or under what circumstances, would it not make sense to try to estimate a coefficient for the first level? It might help to write down the model equations before leaping into R.

Comment: Well, you have the answer: if I might suggest the next step in your investigations; fit a model with 0/1 dummy variables for *all* levels of the categorical predictor, but *without* an intercept, & compare the results - not just the coefficient estimates but the fits.

Answer (score 3):

It helps to compare the matrix created by `lm` to the matrix `X` you constructed by hand:

```
 > head(model.matrix(model))
   (Intercept) admit1        gre rank2 rank3 rank4
 1           1      0 -1.7980110     0     1     0
 2           1      1  0.6258844     0     1     0
 3           1      1  1.8378321     0     0     0
 4           1      1  0.4527490     0     0     1
 5           1      0 -0.5860633     0     0     1
 6           1      1  1.4915613     1     0     0
 > head(X)
      admit        gre rank2 rank3 rank4
 [1,]     0 -1.7980110     0     1     0
 [2,]     1  0.6258844     0     1     0
 [3,]     1  1.8378321     0     0     0
 [4,]     1  0.4527490     0     0     1
 [5,]     0 -0.5860633     0     0     1
 [6,]     1  1.4915613     1     0     0
```

Looks like you forgot the intercept term. That's easy to fix, by adding `X <- cbind(1, X)` before the definition of `Xbeta`. Now `Xbeta` is the same as `coef(model)`:

```
            [,1]
      -0.0458497
admit  0.2497985
gre    0.3681632
rank2 -0.1442362
rank3  0.1418862
rank4 -0.1309418
```